# GRASS not working with QGIS says This algorithm cannot be run

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osgeo4w

I updated QGIS to version 3.6 using OSGEO4w

When I try to run any GRASS script, I get the following error message :

[image: Error message]

> This algorithm cannot be run :-(  The specified GRASS 7 folder
> "C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\bin" does not contain a valid set of GRASS 7 modules.
> Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check that the GRASS
> 7 folder is correctly configured

It looks like the path doesn't exist, but I couldn't find a place to change it; it is not an option in the processing settings any more like in versions 2.x.

Is there a way to run those processing scripts in QGIS 3.6 and if so, how could I tweak the settings needed?

---

Here is what my processing options looks like

[image: Processing parameters]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If I open QGIS with the shortcut "QGIS Desktop 3.6.0 with GRASS 7.6.0" everything works fine. If I open QGIS with the shortcut "QGIS Desktop 3.6.0" I get the same error as you.

**UPDATE for QGIS 3.20:** Please use `qgis.bat` located in  `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` as `qgis-bin-g7.exe` is missing in the latest version.

Comment: I wonder why GRASS is not the default option for starting with QGIS.

Comment: The exact same problem arose again and was resolved by updating the `grass` package with OSGEO4w.

Comment: I do not get the `QGIS Desktop x.x.x with GRASS x.x.x` option at all. I only get the `QGIS Desktop` option. What could be wrong?

Comment: If like me you don't have that shortcut, you can create a new one pointing at "qgis-bin-g7.exe" in the same folder as the QGIS applications for which you already have a shortcut.  In my case, the folder is C:\OSGeo4W64\bin.  This will open GRASS with your current latest version of QGIS.  I use QGIS 3.4 (current long-term release), and so I've changed the shortcut to point to "qgis-ltr-bin-g7".

Comment: For me, i don't have such a shortcut. And it definitely depends on the environment. So I added the line `call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat"` to my qgis batch file, and grass tools work. Of cource the path must be correct and the line should come after that line `call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"`

Comment: I opened the properties of a `.qgz` of mine and changed the app to execute from `qgis.bat` to `qgis-grass7.bat`. Seems to work fine. Now my QGIS project files don't have a nice icon any more, but, well, you know, meh... I'll take care of it when I have time for aesthetics.

Comment: Standalone solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/366866/35561

Comment: Using the option to open QGIS with GRASS worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem but I managed to solve it by renaming my grass folder from "grass76" to grass-7.6.0".

Comment: this will be because the folder path that the bat file is pointing to is still the old one. This still seems to be an issue in later versions, where the OSGEO installer upgrades Grass, but the bat file still points to older grass folder version. You can change either, the folder, or the bat file.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\apps\grass\grass78\` and copy the "bin" folder directly into `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\bin\`.

Now the GRASS modules are in the specified path `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\bin\bin`. 
Done

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this grasswiki-article](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly) setting the operating system environment variable *GISBASE* to the GRASS installation folder might fix the issue (e.g. C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass76).

QGIS 3.8 processing options still doesn't contain an option for the GRASS folder.

I refer to Windows operating system and QGIS 3.8 / GRASS 7.6.

Comment: nailed it on the head for me: no GRASS folder in processing options for QGIS 3.8. There are a few other GRASS-associated folders, but nothing that is distinctly GRASS. I'm using QGIS 3.8.1. With respect to Taras' suggestion that the OP did not launch "QGIS with GRASS", that is not an option for me currently on my machine and may not have been one for the OP either. I know I've had that option in the past, I don't know what I did differently when I installed QGIS on this new (for me) machine to miss it. Adding the new environment path worked for me it seems.

Comment: Fixed it for me!

Comment: With QGIS 3.14 for Windows my answer above isn't valid anymore. But setting the path within *qgis-bin.env* file in QGIS bin folder solves the issue. The QGIS settings dialog still doesn't contain this setting.

Answer (score 5):

To me, it seems like some environment variables are missing when starting the "normal" qgis. I fixed this in QGIS 3.4.13 by changing **qgis-ltr-bin.env** and **qgis-ltr.bat** . In the 3.6, 3.8 (...) version these two files will have a different but similar name. If you

*right click on your qgis start icon > open file path*

this should lead you to ...\OSGeo4W64\bin or wherever you have installed qgis. You´ll find the two files there. Open them with a standard text editor (e.g. notepad) to make changes:

**qgis-ltr-bin.env**:

- change PATH to the same PATH-line that is saved in *qgis-ltr-bin-g7.env* (located in the same folder)
- from *qgis-ltr-bin-g7.env* add the variables GISBASE,GRASS_PROJSHARE and GRASS_PYTHON

**in qgis-ltr.bat**:

- add line 3 from *qgis-ltr-grass7.bat* (located in the same folder): `call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat"` (maybe the grass folder has a different name in your version)
- change PATH to the same PATH-line that is saved in *qgis-ltr-grass7.bat* (line 7)

Comment: Thanks now with QGIS 3.5.15 works.

Answer (score 4):

In respect to a part of your question

> "It looks like the path doesn't exist, but I couldn't find a place to
>   change it; it is not an option in the processing settings any more
>   like in versions 2.x."

you can manage the path of the working GRASS folder through

> Settings > Options > Processing > Providers > GRASS

Based on QGIS 3.0.3 version

[image: GRASS_setting_window]

where you can adjust the `'GRASS7 folder'`, just double click on it.

And by the way, GRASS works fine on my QGIS 3.0.3 version.

Comment: Which version is this screenshot from? I have attached mine, it looks like you have a few more options than I do!

Comment: QGIS 3.0.3 version

Comment: You probably did not launch QGIS with GRASS in it

Comment: The row for "GRASS7 folder" is missing in qgis 3.6 and 3.10 .

Comment: However, it is stable for LTR (QGIS 3.4)

Comment: In Qgis 3.6 and above, go to Plugins>GRASS>GRASS Options  to change the default locations of GRASS folder.

Answer (score 2):

The simple folder name change fix allowed the grass toolbox functions to open in QGIS 3.10. However, when executed, GRASS operations all failed with the following error in the log:

> The system cannot find the path specified. '""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried setting the Windows environmental variable (using the GRASS folder name reverted back to 'grass78'), as described in another answer, and the GRASS operations now execute properly in QGIS. This seems to be the proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input, could you point me to a resource to know which variable to set and where?

Comment: I use Windows 10, so in Windows Explorer: right click **This PC**, select **Properties** then **Advanced system settings**, then **Advanced** tab, then **Environmental Variables**. Click **New...** and enter "GISBASE" in Variable Name, and "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass78" in Variable Value [*NOTE: your path may be different depending on the version of QGIS and/or GRASS you have*]. Click **OK** and you should see the newly created variable added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this message appears when Qgis is open with the option "*Qgis Desktop 3.X*", using this interface Qgis is charged without GRASS Library. So, when someone tries to use a GRASS tool, Qgis doesn't find the GRASS library.

To use GRASS tools it is necessary to open Qgis using "*Qgis Desktop 3.X with GRASS 7*"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to use GRASS in processing ToolBox (with QGIS) is
 to find in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\processing\algs\grass7\` the file `Grass7Utils.py` and to replace the terms:

- `grass-7.` by `grass7` in the code located at line 223 or thereabouts
- then `for version in ['', '7', '76', '74', '72', '71', '70']:`" by `for version in ['', '7', '78', '76', '74', '72', '71', '70']:` in the code located at line 229 or thereabouts.