# Using v.net.connect on QGIS 3?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3

I am trying to find out if the [v.net.connect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.net.html) GRASS tool is on QGIS 3.4 because I'm not finding it anywhere in the toolbox.

I have to be reverting to QGIS 2.18 to run this tool.

Comment: On which platform / OS are you ? Have you execute QGIS with GRASS ... ?

Comment: Confirmed 3.4,3.6 & 3.8 need to be run 'with GRASS' see > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6

Comment: @J.Monticolo is absolutely right. Additionally, please check this source as well [QGIS GRASS Cookbook](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook), mainly the *'Using GRASS 7 Toolbox'*.