# Processing toolbox not working in QGIS 3.4.13

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, qgis-processing

The processing toolbox stopped working in the previous QGIS 3 ltr version I had installed. Now installed 3.4.13 but processing toolbox still not working. I've tried changing the GRASS path without success but none of the processing providers algorithms work - SAGA, etc. I have seen that 3.4 version has some issue with GRASS and so tried to use the Osgeo installer. With this a message displays stating that the GRASS module path is wrong. 
[image]

I have checked and it seems to be correct.

[image]

I have tried looking at the configurations in the settings/advanced tab as the screen print but not really sure what I am looking for here.
[image]

I really don't know what else to do. I've installed/reinstalled using both the network installer and standalone installer many times.

QGIS also crashes with the following message

[image]

If I add a modified bat file do I need to do anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? Does QGIS crash when you try to open the toolbox? Is the button grayed out?

Comment: For example I click on r.reclass and the toolbars across the top grey out momentarily and then nothing else happens

Comment: Try to use clean fresh profile.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please - is that a setting in QGIS?

Comment: I can't interpret the crash included in your latest update. About to how to start with a clean profile, navigate to `C:\Users\Your-User\AppData\Local` and `Roaming` folders, and delete the `QGIS` folders in them.

Comment: Have you tried starting QGIS with the shortcut "QGIS Desktop 3.6.3 With GRASS 7.6.1" instead of just "QGIS Desktop 3.6.3" (or whatever versions you have) as per this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6

Comment: I'm using the latest LTR with GRASS 7.6.1. My GRASS folder is still 76 so used that for the path. No success I'm afraid!

Comment: @humperderp That is a good point. I think that QGIS long-term release latest version (3.4.13) doesn't have a "with GRASS version", because I can't see a `qgis-ltr-grass7.bat`, `qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe` file or something like it. But I run GRASS modules from the _.bat_ file calling the enviroment variables and setting the path.

Comment: Do you know what the latest LTR is that has a GRASS version and how I can download it?

Comment: I just use OSGeo4W, I really appreciate it. I don't like Stand-alone installations because I can't update them easily. I just installed OSGeo4W some time ago (more than one year), and run the Advanced Setup regularly to keep it updated.

Comment: Also, the latest stable QGIS 3.10.0 seems to me better than the long-term release. I would recommend you Install OSGeo4W and try both, stable and ltr. To uninstall, run the uninstaller, remove all remaining QGIS folders from _Program Files_ and _AppData_, and run CCleaner registry cleaner a few times until it doesn't find errors.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

I think I had that problem before.

I use the OSGeo4W 64-bit version. I try to keep the latest stable and long-term release versions of QGIS updated.

In one of the updates, GRASS happened to have version 78 instead of 76, but the file that raised QGIS still referred to the previous folder.

I have the `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-ltr.bat` file with the following content:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat"
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe" %*
```

I have the idea of having modified it by hand one day, replacing all the `grass76` chains with`grass78`.

Now I run that file to run QGIS, which recognizes the *PATH* without problems.

---

If your `qgis-ltr.bat` doesn't have the grass `call` and `path` lines, make sure that you have a `...\apps\grass\grass78` folder, copy that lines from this answer to a new `qgis-ltr_modified.bat` file, to preserve the original, and try running QGIS from it.

Comment: I cleaned my profile and today installed 3.4.13 & GRASS 7.8.1 using OSGeo4W  and all seems to be working

Comment: Good to know it! Was an update last days to the current `qgis-ltr 3.4.13-2`. It is likely that the problem has been solved from there. I hope you find the OSGeo4W update system as good as I see it. Successes!