# GRASS 7 problem

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am working with QGIS 3.8.3. I want to split my lines into intersections and for this, I tried to use the command v.clean in GRASS - Processing Toolbox. However, an error msg appears: 
"This algorithm cannot be run. 
The specified GRASS 7 folder does not contain a valid set of GRASS 7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check that the GRASS 7 folder is correctly configured"

So, I went to Processing Dialog in Providers. There are no GRASS 7, just the GRASS folder. Are they the same thing? 
The GRASS is Activate properly. If they are the same thing I don't understand what I need to do for the algorithm to work. If they are not and I need the GRASS 7 version, how can I incorporate this one in my QGIS?

Comment: Hi Tatiana, welcome to Gis-SE! How did you install QGIS and GRASS? under which Operating System (Windows, OSX, Linux)?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6 ?