# GRASS plugins not loading on Qgis 3.10.13 Coruña LTR

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have QGIS 3.10.13 LTR installed with the stand alone installer on a Windows 10 machine. In this machine I have also  a QGIS 3.16.2 OSGeo installation. I can work perfectly with GRASS in my OSGeo4W install. Nevertheless, I am unable to work with any grass tool in **3.10** (r.reclass, for instance). The dialog box opens, I can fill the information required but processing takes almost no time and I have no output. It is the same situation as described here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34030#

But I have no success on the solution of the problem as exposed at the end of the entry (which is closed also).

QGIS 3.10 log message states that:

> 2021-01-13T11:21:53     WARNING    Failed to load
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/plugins/grassplugin7.dll (Reason:
> Cannot load library
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\grassplugin7.dll: No se
> puede encontrar el módulo especificado.)
>
> 2021-01-13T11:21:53     WARNING    Failed to load
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/plugins/grassprovider7.dll
> (Reason: Cannot load library
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\grassprovider7.dll: No se
> puede encontrar el módulo especificado.)
>
> 2021-01-13T11:21:53     WARNING    Failed to load
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/plugins/grassrasterprovider7.dll
> (Reason: Cannot load library
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\grassrasterprovider7.dll:
> No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.)

Nevertheless, the dlls are present in the directories mentioned on the log message (no se puede encontrar = can not find).

Another piece of information. About a year ago I was having problems running grass and I emplemented the solution by ewolf in this question
[GRASS not working with QGIS 3.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6), with involves defining a path environment variable in Win 10.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled Qgis 3.10, run a registry cleaner. A reinstall solve my problem