# What is the difference between qgis-ltr-bin.exe and qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe for QGIS 3.16?

Tags: qgis-3

QGIS 3.16 has two executable files: `'qgis-ltr-bin.exe'` and `'qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe'`. Which of these files is the preferred one for running QGIS? Is there any difference between these two files?

Comment: Start QGIS with (qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe) or without (qgis-ltr-bin.exe) Grass enabled https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313726/2856. And neither is the preferred method of starting QGIS, you should instead use the appropriate shortcut (which calls a batch file that sets appropriate environment variables before running QGIS with/without grass)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on whether you want to run any Grass algorithms within Qgis, which the "-g7.exe" loads. That's my understanding anyway.