# Tools from grassplugin does not work in QGIS 3.22.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I have a problem with the grassplugin in QGIS 3.22.2 Białowieża.

When I try to use the v.net.alloc (and other grass-tools) from the Processing Toolbox in the standalone QGIS 3.22.2 I get this error:

Starting GRASS GIS...

```
         WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
         
         Cleaning up temporary files...
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         Executing ...
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>chcp 1252 1>NUL 
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/(...)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kpDgte/72ecb67feef54867a8ffc9851f208d7c/crs.prj" 
         
         ERROR: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/(...)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kpDgte/72ecb67feef54867a8ffc9851f208d7c/crs.prj' for reading
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.external input="C:\Users\(...)\Documents\QGIS 3.22.2\Filer\NoWeRoadsClip.gpkg" layer="NoWeRoadsClip" output="vector_61fcfbdc824465" --overwrite -o 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.external input="C:\Users\(...)\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_kpDgte\338535ea2f794f34aa5335eed3b3b187\points.shp" output="vector_61fcfbdc8ac636" --overwrite -o 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>g.region n=3.85878803973861 s=1.67431656130019 e=33.4332991925107 w=30.7408159002858 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.net -s input=vector_61fcfbdc824465 points=vector_61fcfbdc8ac636 output=net61fcfbdc8b4307 operation=connect threshold=50.0 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.db.connect -o map=net61fcfbdc8b4307 table=vector_61fcfbdc8ac636 layer=2 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.net.alloc input=net61fcfbdc8b4307 center_cats="1-100000" arc_type="line,boundary" method="from" output=outputb1bc55ad8d224638b8fd52cf3e777071 --overwrite 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>v.out.ogr type="line" input="outputb1bc55ad8d224638b8fd52cf3e777071" output="C:/Users/(...)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kpDgte/863fe868de224291809e7b8d459c9f4c/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" layer=1 --overwrite 
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         
         
         C:\Users\(...)\Desktop>exit
         
         Execution of finished.
         
         Cleaning up temporary files...
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
```

I have also installed the OSGeo4W version and used the the qgis.bat file, which was recommended in this thread:
[GRASS not working with QGIS 3.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6)). It gives me another, but a similar error:

Starting GRASS GIS...

```
         WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
         
         Cleaning up temporary files...
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
         
         Executing ...
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/(...)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yIaRlg/b0926c67e7da4b55aa86ca1dab885e50/crs.prj" 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.external input="C:\Users\(...)\Documents\QGIS 3.22.2\Filer\NoWeRoadsClip.gpkg" layer="NoWeRoadsClip" output="vector_61fd00041175b5" --overwrite -o 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.external input="C:\Users\(...)\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_yIaRlg\a8f0f145755f45769dc965461000b409\points.shp" output="vector_61fd0004190236" --overwrite -o 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>g.region n=3.85878803973861 s=1.67431656130019 e=33.4332991925107 w=30.7408159002858 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.net -s input=vector_61fd00041175b5 points=vector_61fd0004190236 output=net61fd0004197ed7 operation=connect threshold=50.0 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.db.connect -o map=net61fd0004197ed7 table=vector_61fd0004190236 layer=2 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.net.alloc input=net61fd0004197ed7 center_cats="1-100000" arc_type="line,boundary" method="from" output=outputfd1ccc6cf51a4af3a3f1f3a8f46c256f --overwrite 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>v.out.ogr type="line" input="outputfd1ccc6cf51a4af3a3f1f3a8f46c256f" output="C:/Users/(...)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yIaRlg/9139baba418549199f92fb65bd80661b/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" layer=1 --overwrite 
         
         
         
         C:\OSGeo4W\bin>exit
         
         Execution of finished.
         
         Cleaning up temporary files...
         
         access: No such file or directory
         
         ERROR: LOCATION not available
```

When I open ESGeo4W the "log messages, Plugins" says:

```
2022-02-04T15:21:36     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\plugins\grassplugin7.dll: The module was not found.)
2022-02-04T15:21:36     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins/provider_grass7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\plugins\provider_grass7.dll: The module was not found.)
2022-02-04T15:21:36     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/plugins/provider_grassraster7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\plugins\provider_grassraster7.dll: The module was not found.)
```

But it seems that the files are in the library at the exact path:

[image]

For me it seems that my paths are wrong. Therefore I tried to make the paths more simple, but it didn't work, so now I am back to default settings.

Does somebody out there have a solution? I am not skilled in coding, so I prefer a solution which doesn't consist of coding. Otherwise I need some guidance.

OBS: There is an Ø (danish letter) in some of the paths, where I have typed (...). Could that be the reason for my error?

Comment: Hey, did you install the "qgis-ltr-glass-plugin" when you installed it through the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: Hey Heikki, I tried to install everything I could. That exact file does not appear in my files, but i have two files called "plugin_grass7.dll" and "plugin_grass7.pdb". Does that point on a problem in the installation?

Comment: So when you install through the OSGeo4W installer in the Advanced installation, "qgis-ltr-glass-plugin" is one of the libraries that you can install.

Comment: I went through the installation again, reinstalled "qgis-ltr-grass-plugin". Now it appears in my files, but when I try to use the v.net.alloc tool from the processing toolbox it gives med the same error: LOCATION not available (The first error in my question).

Comment: However, now it seems in my "Log messages" that the grass plugin loads correctly.

Comment: Can you try a different user without the Ø?

Comment: Yes, should I just rename the folder? The reason I have not done so yet is that I am nervous about whether I am destroying some other paths or fundamental settings. Is there a reason to be worried?

Comment: It's your User folder, so you should not rename it. I would try creating a new user account on the machine without the character to test if that is the issue.

Comment: That was exactly the supervising i needed. It works with the new user, thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect. I have added my comments as an answer in case someone else comes across the same issue. Might be worth logging as a bug, it's a bit unfair to the Danish, but I'm not sure if it would be one for QGIS or for GRASS. Probably GRASS based on the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should try installing the "qgis-ltr-glass-plugin" from the OSGeo4W installer in the Advanced installation section.

If that does not resolve the issue you can try creating a new user on your computer without the non-English character "Ø". That will narrow down the issue.